# Scala will hang without output on simple script

Tags: scala

I wrote a little `HelloWorld.scala` with the following contents:

```
object HelloWorld {
    def main(args: Array[String]) {
        println("Hello, world!")
    }
}
```

Compiling and running works:

```
turion@enigmage ~/e/informatisch/scala $ scalac HelloWorld.scala 
turion@enigmage ~/e/informatisch/scala $ scala HelloWorld
Hello, world!
```

However, when called as `scala HelloWorld.scala`, it will simply hang and output nothing.
Adding a line `HelloWorld.main(args)`, as described in other solutions, doesn't help.
Neither does a script with a single line `println("Hello, world!")`.
What am I doing wrong?

(I'm using scala 2.9.2 on gentoo.)

Comment: I think you just have to wait a bit. For me it works anyway.

Comment: It works fine with Scala 2.11.2.

Comment: can you try removing the main method and then doing *object HelloWorld extends App* ?

Comment: @DoomProg, if I remove the main method, where do I put the `println` statement? Directly in the body of the object?

Comment: Yes. object Hello extends App{ println("Hello World.") } But as I see in the answer below it will still not work.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Script invocation has evolved a bit.

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-1173

Your example works in the latest, but using App will fail again:

https://issues.scala-lang.org/browse/SI-4625

So, script snippets are not programs yet.

Your code gets wrapped in a main function when scripted.